# Cheap carburator or not?

Tags: small-engine, lawnmower, generator

I've got a generator(15 years old. Good shape. Briggs engine) gifted to me. It didn't want to start but I was able to get it started by spraying carb cleaner into the choke tube and it ran alright. Enough to get new gas running through it. I started it acouple times, although it wouldn't on choke.  A month later again no start.

As far as I know the carb needs a good cleaning or replacement. Im comfortable replacing it but disassemble and cleaning is a bit out of my ability and it just seems so dang simple to replace.

Here's the thing. I see Amazon sells the carb for 15$ with good reviews. Briggs sells theirs for 150$. There must be a massive quality difference but I can't seem to find a middle ground. Is there that big a difference? Where do y'all source parts?

Comment: I doubt there is much difference. Briggs wants to sell engines ,not carbs.

Comment: 15$ is just so cheap. I'd rather spend 45 on something a bit better

Comment: I just question if it's not all the same carb, $150 vs $45 vs $15. Be sure when you buy the cheapest one (you know you will!) that it's right size, all externally measurable dimensions - float bowl size, bore for in/out flow, bolt pattern, etc. Check any fittings, everything. $15 is not enough to cry about....

Comment: I have found a carburetor on Amazon which says "Genuine Briggs & Stratton Carburetor" for 22 GBP. If that is true (and it's the right model), what's not to like?

Comment: Last carb I bought for my sears weed eater was $9 delivered to my door, works like a champ. Price did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: I had a generator for 15 years. Ever since it was new it had identical problem as yours. I bought a cheap carb from e bay and it worked great until the generator side broke. I'd go with cheap on something this old. And I rarely say go cheap when it comes to repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rebuild kit pricing?

B&S is a long-established company, and a service kit should include all the seals, gaskets, O rings, and probably an air filter, spark plug, and possibly even new jets and a float.

Basic hand tools should be all you need for the job, along with a camera/phone to take lots of pictures during teardown.